# Should I use "of our times" or "of our time"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, time

Basically I want to say, for example, that somebody is "Mark Twain of our times". Will this be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is grammatically correct, but you should say *of our time* because it's idiomatic.

Comment: [This is true](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+our+time%2Cof+our+times&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20our%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20our%20times%3B%2Cc0), but the difference is not so dramatic that the second can be considered *wrong*, just somewhat less common.

Comment: On top of that, the count of "of our time" has probably been inflated by things like "most of our time" and "we have spent enough of our time on this".